# How can I calculate the age of a person in years, months and days in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to calculate the age of a person taking in consideration the years, months and days to check if the person is under 14 or not.The return result should be boolean if the person is under 14 or not.
I tried with this code but I'm getting an error of conversion.

```
        var under14 = false;
        string person.DateOfBirth = "04/01/2012";
        var DateOfBirth = Convert.ToInt32(person.DateOfBirth);
        var ageDifMs = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now) - DateOfBirth;
        var ageDate = new DateTime(ageDifMs);
        var age = Math.Abs(ageDate.Year - 1970);
        if (age < 14)
            under14 = true;
```

Comment: Dates should be stored in `DateTime` not `string`.

Comment: `DateTime.Today.AddYear(-14)` - check if their date of birth is <= that date or not. You may get some interesting scenarios around Feb 29, but that code will cover most cases.

Comment: Try `Convert.ToDate()` instead of `Convert.ToInt32()`